# Passing variable to datatable's select method but produces empty results

Tags: c#, .net, select, datatable

I'm using the following code to pass filename variable to a DataTable Select Statement.But the returned result is null.

```
var filteredDataRows2 = dt.Select("Status = 'Valid' AND Filename ='"+filename+"'");
```

What i'm I doing wrong? Please advise.

UPDATE:
The Datatable `dt` contains values.The filename has multiple spaces in it `eg:my cool file 2018..`,could that be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried `dt.Select("Status = 'Valid'");` to make sure whether or not this is caused by the filename? And what happens when you execute the statement directly in your database (not via C#)?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Results are produced when i remove the filename from the statement.I don't use any database.

Comment: Okay, I see... how about `dt.Select($"Status = 'Valid' AND FileName = \"{filename}\"")`, does that maybe work?

Comment: Tried it .. the program does not produce any results.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Actually it was another issue within a loop.I was using old datatables with no data... its fixed ...Thanks for your help

Comment: Okay, good to know that you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your data in data table that it has any data! that if you want to get it with your condition then test it with this statement.

```
filteredDataRows2 = dt.Select(String.Format("Status = Valid AND Filename = '{0}'", filename));
```

Comment: Thanks... the Datatable contains values .. i have tried your code,but the same issue.. The filename contains multiple spaces... could that be the issue?

Comment: @techno Not Really, because you should try with simple query. for example try without  'Status = 'Valid' AND' and vice versa without 'Filename = '{0}'", filename' .Maybe there is a problem in your condition (query).

Comment: @techno remove your single quotation on the valid, please.

Comment: Tried it... does not produce any output.

Comment: @techno what's your status and filename type ?

Comment: Actually it was another issue within a loop.I was using old datatables with no data... its fixed ...Thanks for your help.

Comment: @techno be successful ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please show the relevant data in the `DataTable` itself; I have created the following minimal example and could not reproduce the behavior you are experiencing.

---

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Filename", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add("Valid", "C:\\Test File With Spaces.txt");
table.Rows.Add("Valid", "C:\\Test File.txt");
table.Rows.Add("Invalid", "C:\\Test File With Spaces.txt");
table.Rows.Add("Valid", "C:\\Test.txt");

string filename = "C:\\Test File With Spaces.txt";

var allRows = table.Select(); // Expected Rows: 4 Actual Rows: 4
var filteredRows = table.Select("Status = 'Valid'"); // Expected Rows: 3 Actual Rows: 3
var filteredRows2 = table.Select($"Status = 'Valid' AND Filename = '{filename}'"); // Expected Rows: 1 Actual Rows: 1
```